# Partial Differential Equation equal to a function

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Hi the question I have to solve is:

$u_x + u_y + u = e^{x+2y} \ $  where $ u(x,0) = 0$

First, I tried to solve the question of the form:

$$ u_x + u_y + u = 0$$

We know that $\dot x = 1 \ $ and $\dot y = 1 \ $. From that we can introduce s where $$x(s) = s +x_0$$ and $$y(s) = s$$. Then if $z = u(x(s), y(s))$ we have that $\dot z + z = 0$.

By setting $s = y$ we have then that $x_0 = y-x$.

Then we can get that $u(x,y) = e^{-y} \ g(y-x)$.

Now, to get $\dot z + z = e^{x+2y}$ I am completely stuck

Comment: Substitution $u(x,y)=f(x,y)e^{x+2y}$ seems useful here.

Comment: This question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124412/solve-the-pde-by-the-method-of-characteristics), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700085/solving-an-inhomogeneous-1st-order-pde-using-method-of-characteristics), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864920/equation-u-xu-e2yx-part-of-the-solution-to-u-xu-yu-ex2y), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127606/finding-particular-solutions-to-pdes-transport-equation).

Comment: And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307258/i-am-trying-to-solve-a-linear-non-homogeneous-pde), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688388/solving-a-first-order-pde-with-initial-value-condition-by-change-of-variable), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443291/solve-u-x-u-y-u-ex2y) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038801/simple-1st-order-pde)

Comment: [Here too.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2471098/solve-u-xu-yu-ex2y-with-ux-0-0)